# trouble with if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

please help me.

I have form like this in index.php

```
<form id="statusForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <textarea name="statusText" role="textbox" id="wallpost"></textarea>
    <input id="photo_input" type="file" name="photo_input" />
    <input type="hidden" name="to_id" value="1" > 
    <button type="button" name="submit" onClick="write_wall_post();">
</form>
<div id="content"></div>
```

then i have .js file to handle this form

```
function write_wall_post()
{

var formData = new FormData($("#statusForm")[0]);
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "act_post_status.php",
        data: formData, 
        success: function(data){
            $("#wallpost").val("");             
            $("#photo_input").val('');
            var newStatus=data;
            $(newStatus).hide().prependTo("#content").fadeIn(2000);
        },
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,
        cache:false
   });
}
```

and i have act_post_status.php to process this file submit

```
<?php 
//some configuration
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{   
    //some variable declaration and image validation
    //Original Image
    if(move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, $path.$time.'.'.$ext))
    {
        $is_image=1;
    }
    else
        echo "failed";
    }
}


 //inserting data to database
   $status = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST["statusText"])));
   mysql_query("insert into news (status,is_image) values ('$status','$is_image')");
   echo "<div class='post'>$status</div>";
?>
```

the scenario i want is:
when user input data (status), then click submit button, the content automatically show the update (handled by jquery)

but the fact is:

(1) when I completed the form (both status and picture), it works normally.

(2) but when I completed just data form (filling status input only), it was submitted to database successfully, but the content don't update automatically. I should refresh them to get the update.

(3) when i just filling the image input, it works normally like case (1).

Please help why if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") failed to echo the input by ajax request when data input (status) is blank/empty.

thousands of thanks. :)

Comment: Where do you set `$uploadedfile`?

Comment: in the code, i have written //some variable declaration and image validation, this is declaration variable section. it's not the point since image can uploaded successfully, and when i filling the image input, it was update successfully.

The problem is when i left the image input empty. the data was submitted to database successfully, but the content doesnt updated automatically (need refresh page).

but when I filling the image input (whether with filling status input or not), the content will updated automatically

Comment: You're probably getting an error when you process the form with no uploaded file. Have you checked the Network tab for errors?

Comment: The bug is probably in the code that the comments stand in for.

Comment: there is no error.. it seems fine.

when i change this code like this (by changing position that insert to database first, print something, than upload image), it works perfectly.

<?php 
//some configuration
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{   
    //some variable declaration and image validation
    //Original Image
    if(move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, $path.$time.'.'.$ext))
    {
        $is_image=1;
    }
    else
        echo "failed";
    }
}


 
?>

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `success` function, does it get to it?

Comment: Look at the response text for the AJAX call in the network tab. Do you see the expected `<div>$status</div>`?

Comment: i've tried to alert something in success function. but there are no  alert at all.

when i change this code, that is by changing position that insert to database first, print something, than upload image, it shows alert.

My guess is because of if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") so it fail to print anything after them. when we print first than call if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") , it shows printed text

Comment: If the success function isn't running, it means the AJAX call is getting an error. Look in the Network tab again. Is it returning a 200 status or some other status code?

Comment: here the status code when i filling the status input with text 'heeeee' (but keep the image input blank)

respond payload
------WebKitFormBoundarydFT4i573lHJL2Bgc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="statusText"

heeeeeeeeeee
------WebKitFormBoundarydFT4i573lHJL2Bgc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_input"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarydFT4i573lHJL2Bgc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_id"

20
------WebKitFormBoundarydFT4i573lHJL2Bgc--

Comment: That's the request from the browser, it's not the response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it matters whether you leave the file input unfilled, but you need to disable the normal form submission when you use AJAX. The `onclick` function should return `false` to do this.

```
<button type="button" name="submit" onClick="write_wall_post();return false;">
```

Comment: it doesnt work too.. :(
The strange is it submitted to database successfully. but dont print anything after if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"), except i fill the image input

some text before it printed successfully

Comment: thanks man. after observe again with your suggestion to alert something in success function, it works. so the problem is not leaving the file input unfilled.

but sorry i cant vote your up since need 15 reputation, but im new here. but many thanks for helping me :)